# using jquery with elements inside a asp:gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am trying to add some style with jquery to some elements inside a grid-view but jquery cannot identify those element. i am trying something like this

`$("name").css("border", "3px solid red");`

thanks

Comment: First, you need a `.` or a `#` in front of `name`, depending on whether it's a class or an ID. Secondly, are you using .NET 4?

Comment: @Graham Clark - `name` i already have # in my code i just forgot to write it her, sorry . and i am using .net 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that .net creates big long ugly names by default.  You may call your select "myinput" but .net turns that into something like "somebiguglylongcontainerid$myinput".  So when you try to find just "#myinput" with jquery, you can't because it doesn't exist.

There are two solutions.  If you are using a late enough version of .net, you can simply set ClientIDMode="static", and this will stop the .net renaming, so it will in fact be called "myinput".

The other solution is to inject the generated ID into your jquery with inline code.  `$("#<%=myinput.ID%>").css("border", "3px solid red");`.

Comment: thank you but i took the easy way with assigning a class to the template and then using that class.but `ClientIDMode="Static"` is very very helpful . thank you